# What is this button called? What does it do?

Tags: android

What is this button called? What does it do?

In the displayed screen, even though the "Data Conn." shows dim, when I click that button I see it as "Bright" - Which view to believe?

Thanks much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [google lens app](https://lens.google/) logo you can do many fun things with this like scanning text from image.

Comment: Thank you, so you think it does not affect settings?

Comment: no its a shortcut to open google lens app